# How do I prove that a free group is generated by its base?

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-groups

Let $G$ be a free group with a base $S$.

How do I prove that $G=\langle S\rangle $ **only using universal property**?

Here's how I proved this. Let $F(S)$ be the free group on $S$ constructed via reduced words on $S$. This construction shows that $F(S)$ is generated by $S$. Since $S\subset F(S)$ and $S\subset G$, there is a group isomorphism between $F(S)$ and $G$ which keeps $S$ fixed. Hence $G=\langle S \rangle$.

However, I think this proof is bad. How do I prove that using only universal property?

> My definition for free group:
>
> Let $G$ be a group.
>
> Then, $G$ is free iff there exists $S\subset G$ such that for any group $H$ and a function $f\in H^S$, there exists a unique $\phi\in Hom(G,H)$ such that $\phi\upharpoonright S=f$

Comment: This is *exactly* (one of) the definitions, so you then have to tell you what is for you "free group with a base".

Comment: @Timbuc Just edited :)

Comment: The definition is $Hom_{Grp}(G,T) = Hom_{Sets}(S,T)$ for any group $T$. Not a single word told about generation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The map of sets $f:S \hookrightarrow G$ factors over the group $\langle S \rangle$, so by the universal property the identity homomorphism $G \to G$ obtained from $f$ factors over $\langle S \rangle \hookrightarrow G$. In particular $\langle S \rangle \hookrightarrow G$ is surjective.

Comment: Thank you :) and here is a similar question. By the construction of $F(S)$, for any $x\in F(S)\setminus\{e\}$, there exists a unique finite sequence $\{a_1,...,a_n\}$ in $S\cup S^{-1}$ such that $x=a_1\cdots a_n$. Can universal property alone prove this for a free group with a base $S$?

Comment: Categories don't know elements of objects. So universal properties alone should not be capable of proving such results.